# Image.onload not working for .jpg images changed to .png

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events, mime

I am working on an Cordova windows10 app where I capture images as 'jpg' using  (`navigator.camera.getPicture(resolve, reject, {...encodingType: 0,...}`), move it to another location by changing the extension as '.png' and currently trying ti resize it. However, when I try to load the picture, it doesn't load but throws:

> DOM7009: Unable to decode image at url: '.../myimage.png' to MIME 'image/png'.

It works perfectly if the image was captured as '.png' but not if the image was originally a '.jpeg' and extension changed to '.png'. I do the following things before trying to load image.

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let image = new Image();
image.src = fileSystemPath + imageName // I get : ms-appdata:///local/randomgeneratedID.png

image.onload = function() {
  ...
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, myHeight, myWidth);
  callback(canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 0.9))
  ...
}
```

The issue is that the image is not loading at all. I console.logged right inside the `image.onload` function and it's not showing up. Not sure why it loads '.png' file but not '.jpg' file renamed as '.png'.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the image is not loading at all. I console.logged right inside the image.onload function and it's not showing.

I would suppose that your *.png* image is pretty heavy:

> It works perfectly when the image is captured as '.png'

whereas your new *.png* (ex-jpeg) image is of light weight:

> move it to another location by changing the extension as '.png' and resize it to thumbnail.

What might have happened there is that you **first** set `img.src` to a value - and the actual loading begins right in this moment, but **the handler is set later**. So, if an image is pretty tiny/cached (you wrote you resize them) it can be downloaded before the handler is even assigned. Try to do it this way:

```
image.onload = function() // handler first
image.src = fileSystemPath + imageName // loading next
```

Hope it is useful info. Even if your issue isn't the one I have been talking about, what I wrote remains valid for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The .png is smaller than the original .jpg I captured (I use cordova's `moveTo()` method to move file). I do assign the full path to image.src before doing the image.onload which works ok on iOS though. As you said, I tried assigning the src after loading the image but the app unfortunately can't load old images inside the app and crashes.

Comment: The resizing happens after the image is loaded (unfortunately not happening) by drawing the loaded image on a canvas context. I then do the `getDataUrl`thing to get Base64 string from the image url

Comment: you wrote "the app unfortunately can't load old images inside the app and crashes." So, it works ok for new images that you capture? And what do you mean under "crash"?

Comment: btw, you are missing `;` after `image.src = fileSystemPath + imageName` as well. It might cause some troubles too.

Comment: The app has some persistant images and when I assign the image source after image onload the app doesn't start at all (pretty huge app -.-). The semicolon is a typo ;)
Regarding the old image not loading issue, I'm trying to create some method that loads old image normally but any new image captured with camera gets it's `src` attribute set after getting fully loaded. I will inform you how it goes. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bijay Timilsina ok, keep me posted. I am not really familiar with webviews, and quick search didn't give me any well-known, huge troubles/bugs/issues regarding img's `onload()` handler. I believe the "web" part of this story should work as I described. I mean it is the right way to handle image loading on the web. I wish you luck in making it all work properly!

Comment: Hi, I think I somehow know the issue. It's that if the original file is 'jpg' but I rename the extension to 'png' and try to resize this png file, I'm getting `DOM7009: Unable to decode image at Url: 'ms-appdata:///local/myImage.png' to MIME 'image/png''. Something about mime-sniffing going on in windows platform but I'm looking on it :)

Comment: ok, sounds sensible. so, it is likely to be related to images' encoding format. Seems that simple renaming is not enough and actual converting is needed.